# Extract or Unpack maven ear file to m2 repository format

Tags: maven, extract, ear, unpack

I have done ear packaging using Maven-ear-plugin. Now for my project purpose, I need to revert back(unpack) to same folder structure as m2 repository layout.How can I do this. or is it possible..?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to take a look at the [true-zip-maven-plugin.](http://mojo.codehaus.org/truezip-maven-plugin/)